# How to pass the validation code to the Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to customize the email that AWS Cognito sends if a user has forgotten their password.

It requires {####} placeholder for the verification code in the email message. For example, if you do
`event['response']['emailMessage'] = "Your code is {####}"`, you'll receive a message `Your code is 123456`.

Here's an example of my AWS Lambda function:

```py
def custom_message_handler(event, context):
    event['response']['emailSubject'] = 'Custom subject'
    event['response']['emailMessage'] = 'Custom email'
    # verification_code = event[...] ???
    return event
```

It seems like Cognito generates the verification code after your lambda returned the message with the placeholder. Is it possible to get the verification code inside your lambda to use it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it would not be possible to utilize the numerical verification code inside a Lambda function.

Comment: @lightyagami You can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Cognito's Custom Message Lambda Trigger's Event JSON does not get the numerical verification code. The data of the Event available to the trigger, as stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html) is stated as follows:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "triggerSource": "CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser",
  "region": "<region>",
  "userPoolId": "<userPoolId>",
  "userName": "<userName>",
  "callerContext": {
      "awsSdk": "<calling aws sdk with version>",
      "clientId": "<apps client id>",
      ...
  },
  "request": {
      "userAttributes": {
          "phone_number_verified": false,
          "email_verified": true,
           ...
      },
      "codeParameter": "####",
      "usernameParameter": "username"
  },
  "response": {
      "smsMessage": "<custom message to be sent in the message with code parameter and username parameter>"
      "emailMessage": "<custom message to be sent in the message with code parameter and username parameter>"
      "emailSubject": "<custom email subject>"
  }
}
```

You would be able to use Cognito data in a Lambda trigger only if it is available in an Event, or if there is a separate API call for the same. But given Amazon Cognito's design, this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification